# Taking too long to post image file to parse using swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm trying to get the image from photo library and saving it in parse. My post button code looks like this:

```
let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.imagePicked!, 0.2)
let imageFile = PFFile(name: "image.png", data: imageData!)

questions["picImage"] = imageFile
questions.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {(success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if (success) {
        print("Posted")
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true , completion: nil)
    } else {
        print("Error")
    }
}
```

But it is not being saved .. Taking too long like ever. Thanks for your time.

Comment: depends on internet connection as well as parse number of connections. Note : parse is closing down so bugs can come up any time too

Comment: You should forego efforts in Parse infrastructure. They are shutting down early 2017. Look into AWS or something similar thats guaranteed to last if you need a backend

Comment: why do you say about firebase?